# Unable to install "leaps" and "dyplr" in R Studio

Tags: r, r-package

I have R Studio installed on my office laptop. I am able to install various packages but there are some packages I am unable to install. eg. leaps. I get the following error message. Any help to resolve would be much appreciated. I tried downloading the package manually from cran on my desktop but can figure how to install it.

```
 install. Packages("leaps")
```

Error message:

```
>"trying URL 'http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/leaps_3.1.zip'
> Warning in install.packages :
>  downloaded length 0 != reported length 0
> Warning in install.packages :
>  cannot open URL 'https://cran.wustl.edu/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/leaps_3.1.zip': HTTP status was '403 > Forbidden'
>Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
>  cannot open URL 'http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/leaps_3.1.zip'
>Warning in install.packages :
>  download of package ‘leaps’ failed
>
```

I tried manually downloading the package from cran but can't figure how to install it in R Studio. I tried a few solutions on stackoverflow like using `install.packages("C:/Users/xxx1/Downloads/leaps_3.1.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")`, even that doesn't work.

I tried another solution shared using devtools but i get another error as below -

```
devtools::install("C:/Users/mmyer1/Downloads/leaps_3.1.zip/leaps_3.1")
>Error in `package_file()`:
>! C:/Users/mmyer1/Downloads/leaps_3.1.zip/leaps_3.1 is not a directory.
>Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```